# Why and how maximum force is $\frac{dF}{dx}=0$?

Tags: differentiation

In an certain question my teacher asked to find the maximum force. She said that the maximum force in electrostatics means $\frac{dF}{dx}=0$. Why is it like that?

Comment: The maximum(more precisely extremum) of any analytic function $f(x)$ means $\frac{df}{dx}=0$

Comment: You need also $\frac{d^2F}{dx^2}<0$ at the extremum in order for that extremum to be a maximum.

Comment: While plotting a graph of F v/s x, and the graph reaches a maximum value, the tangent at THAT maximum WILL be parallel to the x axis! Try it out yourself - pen + paper. This implies slope = 0, and slope is nothing but $\frac{df}{dx}$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's a mathematics question, not physics.

Answer (score 6):

Pretty basic result from elementary calculus, nothing to do with electrostatics.

[image]

Comment: Edit accepted. (hurray unilateral decision making ;) Feel free to retag as you see fit, and then feel free to flag this comment for deletion. (or it seems to have been retagged anyway...)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a general principle of physics - it's just an instance of single-variable calculus. Presumably you have some 1-dimensional setup, where at each point $x$ you can calculate the force $F$. Then, assuming $F$ is a differentiable function of $x$, any local maximum of $F$ must be at a point such that $F'(x) = 0$. Of course, $F'(x) = 0$ is not *sufficient*, for it also describes local minima, etc. Moreover, even if there is only one local maximum, this is only guaranteed to be a global maximum if you have some other piece of information lying around such as "$F \to 0$ for $x$ sufficiently far away."

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the graph 
There is no any point except pt M in the graph which may have maximum value than M 
And at the pt M if we draw a tangent then we will find the slope of tangent zero i e dy/dx =0 
That's why if we called to find maximum value then 
We have to solve dy/dx=0 
[image]